# Error in Uploading local file to Azure Blob Container?

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-storage

I have written below code in typescript, which uses Azure client library to upload blobs to Azure Storage. But while uploading from the local path, I'm getting below error in console window.
Is the path format to upload local file is correct and what may be cause of below error?

> Error: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

```cs
const localFilePath = "G:\SampleTestData\DTM\image1.jpg";

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`,credentials);
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(containerName);
const blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();

blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath);
```

Comment: I'm guessing that either that file doesn't exist or this process doesn't have permission to access it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try with forward slash:

```
const localFilePath = "G:/SampleTestData/DTM/image1.jpg";
```